# iOS why my cookie becomes null when I visit particular page

Tags: ios, session-cookies, wkwebview, autologin

I have many webpages and I have session cookie which helps the pages get auto logged in my wkwkebview.

The session cookie is fetched as a part of my login mechanishm so whenever I load any of my webpage it gets auto logged in.

Please note that the session expiry time is more than a day and it doesn't expire.

When I load particular URL under certain scenario , the loading page nullfies the cookie in cookiestorage.

This causes auto-login failure in all the webpages that I load in wkwebview

I don't know why it happens and how Can I fix it ?

Comment: What name are you giving the cookie? Try naming your cookie something different and see if the other URL is unsetting or overwriting your cookie prematurely. Full disclosure - I literally know nothing about iOS or WKWebview.

Comment: What is the URL you are visiting when the cookie is being cleared?

Comment: @AayushSinha  - Just one of the URLs our company has. When I visit , not always this cookie becomes nullified , but sometimes it gets nullified.

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView has a scheduler which handle cookies, the scheduler sync cookies with WKHTTPCookieStore its own schedule (maybe one minute)

I think you have to sync the cookies into WKHTTPCookieStore manually when the login mechanism is finished

Comment: This has been done I guess. But why the working cookies gets nullified and I'm wondering why. Why this happens after visiting the particular URL and particular scenario

Comment: I'm saying there is no problem with how cookie is managed because it works always but sometime it gets nullified

Answer (score -1):

Dan, first you need to clarify the trigger.

Now you say "sometimes" - which means, you're missing some key detail to understand why does this happen.

Try to visit the page in question with "fresh" cookies, with cookies that are close to be expired, for example...Try to emulate the "wrong" behaviour as close as possible.

The idea is to clarify the scenario to ensure 100% reproducibility of the issue.
Before that it's hard to troubleshoot, it's more of a guessing now.

Comment: basically ,,, my confusion .. how a cookie can get removed from cookie store ? for sure it's added when we sign in .. but under some circumstance... cookie gets removed while visiting a web page... I don't understand.. how .. if cookie expires.. will it get removed from cookie store ? please help me